# White boundary at the bottom of screen

Tags: 20.04, display

I can't get a screenshot of it but I have a white rectangular area at the bottom of my screen and it does not go away. It is preventing me from looking at what I am typing at the bottom of the screen . This is my configuration -

```
Linux gansub-OptiPlex-7050 5.15.0-69-generic #76~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Mar 20 15:54:19 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

This is the output of lspci | grep VGA

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 63 0 (rev 04)
```

My version of Ubuntu is 20.04 LTS.

Do I need to install some display drivers again ? I am using the default ones.

EDIT - The problem started off as a white line at the bottom of the screen that ran from left to right but has now become a continuous area of white. About 1 centimeter in height.

Comment: @Nmath It doesn't show up on screenshots. It shows up as perfectly normal.

Comment: If the problem was with a driver or some other software, it would likely show up in the screenshot. You might want to try a different display cable or port.